# How to 'alias' table and all columns at same time in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, rename

I'm trying to use natural join to join two tables in mySQL that have a field that is equivalent, but named differently between the tables (I have to use natural join -- I know it would be easier to use a different join). Natural join looks for fields with the same name, so I want to rename the column in one table to the same name as the one in the other table. In my textbook (not specific to mySQL) it says that the following should work:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address
FROM (EMPLOYEE NATURAL JOIN
(DEPARTMENT AS DEPT (Dname, Dno, Mssn, Msdate)))
WHERE Dname=‘Research’;
```

The part that I'm interested in is the "DEPARTMENT AS DEPT (Dname, Dno, Mssn, Msdate)"... But I can't replicate this in mySQL (it causes an error that says to check for the right syntax to use near '(Dname, Dno, Mssn, Msdate)'. Is there some way to (simply -- without a nested SELECT/FROM query) rename individual columns like this in mySQL so that the natural join sees the columns as equivalent?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why must you use `NATURAL JOIN`?

Comment: @cheeken I have to use natural join because it's a homework assignment that has me do the same query using different joins -- one of which is natural join (I guess just so we get the feel for how the different joins work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you create an `ALIAS` in MySQL:

for `FIELD` (or *columns*) and `TABLE`

```
SELECT FName `FirstName`, LName `LastName
FROM `TableName` `NewName`
```

result:

```
FirstName  ||   LastName
++++++++++++++++++++++++
records here...
```

Comment: This is what I am doing right now (and it works), but I was wondering if there was a different way to do it (without an extra SELECT/FROM query, as I stated in my question). My textbook seemed to think there was another way.

Answer (score 1):

We really need to know the names of the columns. I'll guess you are joining on `EMPLOYEE.Dno = DEPARTMENT.Id` and that `Address` in the resultset comes from the `DEPARTMENT` (otherwise why do the join at all?):

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address
  FROM EMPLOYEE 
       NATURAL JOIN
       (
        SELECT Id AS Dno, Dname, Address
          FROM DEPARTMENT
       ) AS DEPT
 WHERE Dname = 'Research';
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address
  FROM EMPLOYEE 
       NATURAL JOIN
       (
        SELECT Id AS Dno, Address
          FROM DEPARTMENT
         WHERE Dname = 'Research'
       ) AS DEPT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address
FROM (EMPLOYEE NATURAL JOIN
(DEPARTMENT AS DEPT (DEPT.Dname, DEPT.Dno, DEPT.Mssn, DEPT.Msdate)))
WHERE DEPT.Dname=‘Research’;
```

Comment: it's not happy with that either. it seems to basically take offence at anything other than just a new TABLE name after the AS.